# What is the difference between a rule switch and a regular switch in Java?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I couldn't find this question anywhere else so I figured I might as well ask it. Is it purely aesthetic? Is it faster in any way? What are the main differences between the two? By regular switch, I mean

```
switch(var){
    case 1:
        break;
}
```

and by rule switch, I mean

```
switch(var){
    case 1 -> {}
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/switch-expressions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the regular switch you can omit to `break` the execution at the end of a code block. This allows a fall-through, and you can handle several different cases with the same code.

```
switch(var) {
    case 1:
      dosomething();
      break;
    case 2:
      dosomethindelse();
            // the break was forgotten
    case 3:
    case 4: // these cases shall work on the same code
      doanotherthing();
            // but the break was forgotten
    default:
      donothing();
}
```

This advantage is also a disadvantage since the `break` can easily be forgotten and then lead to difficult to spot bugs.

Therefore the rule switch was introduced, which - by it's different syntax does not require a `break` and thus prevents such situations.

Comment: I already knew about ```break``` bugs like that, and didn't realize it before I asked the question. Hopefully this answer can reach the people that need it. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Java is incorporating functional programming into the language.  The second switch is equivalent to pattern matching in functional language such as Ocaml.

Here's an example of counting the number of elements in a list in Ocaml.

```
let mylist = [1;2;3;4;5;6];;

let rec count lst = match lst with
  | [] -> 0
  | h::t-> 1 + (count t);;

count mylist;;
```

We can accomplish the something similar with Java 21.

```
static record Node (int value, Node next){};
  
static int count(Node n){
   return switch(n){
      case null -> 0;
      case Node h-> 1 + count(h.next);
   };
}
  
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Node list = list = new Node(1, new Node(2, null));
  System.out.println(count(list));
}
```